# Django function as Charfield Choices

Tags: django, django-models

Consider the following models with the following fields:

**Powers**:

```py
class Power(models.Model):
    ...
    half = models.BooleanField()
    micro = models.BooleanField()
```

**UseP**:

```py
class UseP(models.Model):
    ...
    power_policy = models.ForeignKey(Power, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def use_types():
        TYPES = []
        TYPES.append(("F", "Full Use"))
        if power_policy.half:
            TYPES.append(("H", "Half Use"))
        if power_policy.micro:
            TYPES.append(("M", "Micro Use"))

        return tuple(TYPES)

    use_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=use_types())
```

The function doesn't run. As you can see, when I try without the "self" arguments, it says that `power_policy` is not defined. If I do it like `self.power_policy`, it recognizes the power policy but then when I got and call the function like `use_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=self.use_types())`, it says that the `self` keyword is not defined in this line.

I think the code explains it all, but in case it doesn't I want to provide choices to my user after they choose the Power, according to the power option. For which, I created a function but it doesn't really seem to work. What am I doing wrong or is it not even possible like this?

Thank You for your time,

Answer (score 1):

If you create a method in your class, which uses fields from that class - you have to pass `self` argument to your method.

Change your method to:     `def use_types(self):` then you can use your fields like `self.power_policy`.

You cannot use your field `use_type` like this. If you want to set `use_type` based on `power_policy` field you can do this in your save method like so:

```
def save(*args, **kwargs):
    if self.power_policy and self.power_policy.half:
        self.use_type = 'H'
    elif self.power_policy and self.power_policy.micro:
        self.use_type = 'M'
    return super(UseP, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not what I want. I've updated my question. If you look closely, my function returns a tuple of tuples which are choices based on the `power_policy` my user chooses.